# На чем разработан блокчейн?

Tags: криптография, криптовалюта, блокчейн

Всем доброго времени суток. Расскажите пожалуйста на каком языке программирования пишется блокчейн? Есть ли простые примеры написания? Может есть какая литература по этому вопросу? Интересуют только решения с нуля не апи и не готовые решения.

Comment: На любом языке пишется, это ж криптография

Comment: на любом языке, какой больше нравиться. но лучше взять что нибудь компилируемое в связи с объемными расчетами. Статей и литераторы в связи с модностью темы вокруг валом

Comment: Как так на любом? Давайте не путать. Криптография это метод шифрования данных. А я хочу сделать децинтрализованную базу данных в которой будут храниться как раз таки блоки с криптографией.

Comment: Хранение байт уже лучше ответ. но хотелось бы больше информации. С чего начать может книгу посоветуете может статьи с примерами ?

Comment: Если бы я не поискал самостоятельно то не писал бы сюда. Инфы много но не по теме создания. Если вы сами не знаете тему просьба дальше не засорять своими комментариями пост.

Comment: Плохо искали. Хотя бы вот: https://habrahabr.ru/post/347930/ или вот: https://habrahabr.ru/company/otus/blog/342974/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Список самых популярных есть в интернете. 
Посмотри статью:Написание blockchain менее чем за 200 строк кода на Go.

---

А вообще можно на чем угодно написать. А если не писать-то можешь **траслировать** в любой язык. Пиши на PHP-транслируй в джаву.
Если пройтись по гитхаб репам популярных реализаций блокчейна то в основном используется C/C++ и Golang.
Ethereum — написан на Go, для контрактов своя виртуальная машина EVM + язык Solidity
Bitcoin и его форки — C++

---

Полный список из вакансий поиска разработчиков:

> Node.js С++ C++, Go or Python Java Python, Go, JavaScript Solidity,
>   JavaScript or C# PHP, Go, Ruby, Python, JavaScript Solidity, Go,
>   JavaScript, PHP PHP, JavaScript, Python, C++, Solidity Java  Java or
>   Golang Java  Solidity, NodeJS, Go, Python, C++, Java Solidity,
>   JavaScript Node.JS JavaScript C/C++, Go Golang or Python Perl 
>   Solidity, Node.js  C++/Rust, NodeJS Go, JavaScript